# Find distinct values from two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that goes something like this...

```
A        B
100      423
100      423
323      123
323      153
323      153
521      321
521      321
321      321
```

How do i write a query so that it only gets the unique A AND B?
I want the result to look like this.

```
A        B
100      423
323      123
323      153
521      321
321      321
```

So far, I can only make it group by unique of one column using

```
select * from ABtable group by A
```

which gives

```
A        B
100      423
323      123
521      321
```

or...

```
select * from ABtable group by B
```

would return

```
A        B
100      423
323      123
323      153
321      321
```

but not both.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT blah blah blah - but this 'table' doesn't have a PK, so it ain't really a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by multiple columns...

```
Select *
From   ABTable
Group By A, B
```

Depending on the table definition and possible where/having clauses you may see a slight performance increase using distinct instead

```
Select Distinct A, B
From   ABTable
```

Benchmark and decide.

Comment: The queries are equivalent (if the database is smart enough to see that `*` matches the group by.)  Why would `distinct` perform better depending on the table definition?

Comment: Not sure, but a few years back we switched from Distinct to Group By on a table with > 10M records and did find a significant performance boost

Answer (score 0):

To have distinct rows, you need to do

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM ABTABLE
```

To group by A, you need to choose an aggregate function for B, just as `SUM`,`AVG`,`MAX`,`MIN`,`COUNT`, etc... In your output example, you are using `MIN`, then the query would be:

```
SELECT A, MIN(B)
FROM ABTABLE
GROUP BY A
```

If you want to count B elements you would use:

```
SELECT A, COUNT(B)
FROM ABTABLE
GROUP BY A
```

And it will return the number of elements in B which are different from `NULL`